# Laravel Project - Sending null request

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on laravel project and the part of project I am having issues with is edit users profile. 
Every user have right to edit his/hers profile informations etc. but seems like when I fill all fields except password it changed. I tried to

```
dd($request->all())
```

and it showed me that

```
'password' => null,
```

Is it possible to check if some fields does not have inserted value and if they are empty to not be sent in request? I tried

```
$request->filled('password')
```

and

```
$request->has('password')
```

but in both cases it sent null.

The problem with this is when I log out and try to login I cant because the password is changed but I dont know which is. Then I need to use tinker to change it back.

Here is current part from controller and blade.php

**Controller**

```
if($request->filled('password')){
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
}

$user->save();
$user->profile->save();
```

**Blade**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">New password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Forgot to mention when I fill password field and update it works just fine. Problem is when it is sent empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just simply to check password is null in your controller:

```php
if($request->input('password')){
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
}
```

Comment: thank you, seems like it is working properly now :D gonna check in docs what does input do